# Yet Another 'The Breakpoint will not currently be hit' error for a JS file in my startup project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

My company has hired another company to re-write our janky ASP / VB.NET web application to use C#, MVC 5, and the Razor View Engine.

Today, we've received the project back and I'm having some difficulties trying to determine why I cannot log in to the application.

We have a working copy setup on one of our internal testing environments, but while trying to setup my local dev / test environment I am unable to get things going. My boss said he hasn't set it up yet either so he won't be of any help. I don't know who set up QA's test environment.

Anyways, I've matched my local IIS settings as closely as I can to the settings on the functioning test environment. When I launch the application and enter my credentials, I just see a spinning 'loading' icon which then disappears and does nothing. If I enter in bad data or missing data, the software prompts me with the appropriate errors.

I've tried to set a breakpoint in the JS that gets called to validate the login form but I just get the "breakpoint will not be current, no symbols loaded" error.

This solution has 4 projects in it, and the JS file in question is in the startup Project that contains the login page.

This startup project, `MyProject.Web`, contains the Views\Central\CentralLogin.cshtml file and ....\Scripts\Central\Central.js file (which the view does have a reference to).

I've gone to Debug -> Modules and it told me the .PDB was out of date. Clean, rebuild, copy the file over to the directory specified (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\MyProject.Web.pdb). Re-launch the application and it says "Symbols loaded" when I re-open the "Symbol Load Information" screen. Despite that, setting a breakpoint in the JS gives the same "No symbol loaded" error.

I've tried restarting IIS, restart the app pool, clean & rebuild my solution, copy over the new pdb to the folder it says it's looking at. As far as I can tell my IIS configuration matches our working test site. I also tried changing the Solution to contain "multiple startup projects" rather than specifying a single project.

Solution Configuration is set to Configuration: Debug, Platform: Any CPU. I've tried IE, Chrome, and Firefox. All 3 give the same results.

Any ideas what else I might try? I read through at least 3 different StackOverflow posts citing this error and none of the solutions worked for me.

The button on my page is defined as such:

```
<input tabindex="1" name="btnCredLogin" id="btnCredLogin" class=" button button-primary" type="button" value="Login" onclick="ValidateForm();">
```

Below that button, outside of the `</html>` tag, is this snippet of Razor code:

```
@{
    var jsReference = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DOWNLOADVERSION"].ToString();
}

<script src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Central/Central.js?v=" + jsReference)></script>
```

And it's that `Central.js` file which contains the `ValidateForm()` method that the button click event points to. The app settings key to which `jsReference` refers simply contains the value `"1.0"`. So it's looking for `Central.js?v=1.0`. I tried scrapping that `?v=1.0`, so it just points to `Central.js`, but it doesn't change the results.

I'm absolutely clueless as to why I cannot debug this JS file. Any clues?

Comment: I've pretty much given up trying to set breakpoints in javascript with Visual Studio.  Instead I just type debugger; in the javascript.  Whenever execution reaches the line with debugger; it breaks execution and lets me debug from there.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that VS isn't the best debugging tool.  I would suggest using Chrome.  Within Chrome developer tools settings,  hit F1 and be sure the 'disable caching' is checked.

For sanity check, I would break on your server CentralLogin code. I have gone thru a similar situation, and I was pointing to the wrong server. I'll never get those 3 hours back....

Your js callback is ValidateForm().  I would do a search all files for that method name.  Maybe there is another js file that is declaring this in the same global js scope and overwriting the one that you are looking for.

Then try to open up the page in Chrome dev tools and to to the source tab.  Find your ValidateForm() function and set the breakpoint and then reload the page.

You could put a ValidateForm() function in a script block on the cshtml page with an alert to see if that works.